# kernel compilation make command error

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am trying to compile linux-4.4.39 kernel in my 4.4.0-59-generic(Host computer) platform. In my first step `make menuconfig` it works fine and generated `.config` file. But in second step make it throwing an error like below...

```
vinod@SYS_DELL:~/linux-4.4.39$ make
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  HOSTCC  scripts/sign-file
scripts/sign-file.c:23:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.host:91: recipe for target 'scripts/sign-file' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/sign-file] Error 1
Makefile:556: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

I am new to kernel compilation. Please provide solution to my problem.

Comment: Do you have the libssl-dev package installed? It is needed ever since kernel 4.3-rc1.

Comment: thanks mr. Smythies i missed it and now i installed and tried its working now

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this as an actual answer; the comment on the question from [Doug Smythies](https://askubuntu.com/users/372967/doug-smythies) is correct, you will need to install the package libssl-dev to resolve this error. 
Command:
`sudo apt install libssl-dev`